# Angular Reactive Form Validation: Do not allow a number less than existing number

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

I have a numeric input field in Angular reactive form.

```
 <input id="referenceNumber" type="number" formControlName="referenceNumber" />
 <div *ngIf="form.referenceNumber.invalid && (form.referenceNumber.dirty || form.referenceNumber.touched)">
    <span *ngIf="form.referenceNumber.errors?.required">
       Please Enter a number.
    </span>
 </div>
```

I want to show an error message on entering a value less than initial value. Do I need to create a custom validator or is there an easier way to do the same.

Comment: When you create the form, you add this initial value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set initial value on your input and you are use the built in Validators.min validator. You set as min number your initial value.

```
var initialValue: number;

this.form = this.fb.group({
    referenceNumber: [initialValue. 
    Validators.min(initialValue),
    Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]\d*$/) ])
});
```

html

```
<span *ngIf="myForm.get('referenceNumber').errors.min">
     numberInputName cannot be more than {{ initialValue }}. 
</span>

<span *ngIf="myForm.get('referenceNumber').errors?.pattern">
 numberInputName must be greater than zero
</span>
```

Comment: How can I show two separate error messages a) one for less than zero b) one for between zero and given range

Comment: If the number is less than zero you want a seperate error message?

Comment: @MadhurMaurya i update my answer with a second pattern validator which allow numbers greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks @Tzimpo I was trying the same. Won't it display both error messages when input it some negative number say (-1). I handled it by applying double checks in *ngIf such that only only validation passes through.

Comment: @MadhurMaurya Great!